# How to do bulk text replacement in Eclipse?

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

I'm trying to replace the line below (existing on more than 1000 java file) with my own line but I don't know how to do it on Eclipse.

```
Image.getInstance(pathConverter.getAbsolutePath("common/img/filename.jpg"));
```

"filename" is different on each java file.

I'm trying with this but it doesn't work (I'm not good at regular expression)

```
Image.getInstance(pathConverter.getAbsolutePath("common/img/(.*)"));
```

What is the correct regular expression for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

Search -> File Search -> Enter regex -> Click Replace ->

Regex is

```
Image\.getInstance\(pathConverter\.getAbsolutePath\("common/img/.*\.jpg"\)\);
```

You need to escape the `.`, `(`, `)` in your path with `\`

Answer (score 1):

Simple, follow these steps :

1. Go to Search and then File.
2. Enter text, file pattern and projects.
3. Replace
4. Enter New text.

and you are done.